# Creating table in Databricks using the table from Oracle

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a table in Databricks  using a object in Oracle Db, but getting an error

```
aSql = f"""CREATE TABLE TEST_TAB_EMP
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  url "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost.com:1560/ORCL",
  dbtable "SCOTT.EMP",
  user "ABC",
  password "****"
  oracle.net.encryption_client "REQUIRED",
  oracle.net.encryption_types_client "(AES256)",
  oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client "REQUIRED",
  oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion "false"
)"""

print(f"Creating table TEST_TAB_EMP.. ")

spark.sql(aSql)
```

### ERROR

```
ParseException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3083394460508250> in <module>
     14 print(f"Creating table TEST_TAB_EMP... ")
     15 
---> 16 spark.sql(aSql)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in sql(self, sqlQuery)
    707         [Row(f1=1, f2=u'row1'), Row(f1=2, f2=u'row2'), Row(f1=3, f2=u'row3')]
    708         """
--> 709         return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
    710 
    711     @since(2.0)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1304         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 
   1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    131                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    132                 # JVM exception message.
--> 133                 raise_from(converted)
    134             else:
    135                 raise

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in raise_from(e)

ParseException: 
extraneous input 'oracle' expecting {')', ','}(line 8, pos 2)

== SQL ==
CREATE TABLE TEST_TAB_EMP
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  url "jdbc:oracle:thin:@dm12-scan.cloud1.cibc.com:1528/ECW1S",
  dbtable "SCOTT.EMP",
  user "ABC",
  password "****"
  oracle.net.encryption_client "REQUIRED",
--^^^
  oracle.net.encryption_types_client "(AES256)",
  oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client "REQUIRED",
  oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion "false"
)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a comma after the line where you specify the password? All lines within the options section have a comma at the end of the line, except the line before where the error is raised.

Comment: Yes, I tried. Now i am getting below error. I am new to Python & Spark so not able to figure it out what could be the issue   om.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$